# How can I decrease the size of a particular group of an independent nominal variable within a sample without compromising the integrity of the sample?

Tags: sample-weighting

Our team conducted an online survey to discover citizens' attitude on a particular topic. The total number of responses collected is 900. It's apparent that this is a non-probability sample of convenience. Despite our attempt to mitigate bias with sample weighting, we have encountered a significant obstacle. When comparing the observed proportion of 48% in the age group of ‘18-24 years’ to the population proportion of 18%, the weight assigned is 0.38. The proportion of those who are 65+ years or older is greatly diminishing, resulting in a higher weight of 3. Our sample is being adjusted for gender, age, and education. Although the maximum weight on demographic variables is only 3, the final weight for individuals over the age of 65 exceeds this at 14. Combining groups into one does not solve this problem. The possibility of imposing a maximum weight of 5 was considered, but it was determined that this would only contribute to a greater bias. What steps can we take to address this challenge? If we were to randomly choose a sample, a size of 300 would be ideal. Is it possible to reduce our sample size while excluding part of the 'age 18-24' group and still maintain the validity of the sample? Or..Do someone has any other suggestion?
Thank you in advance